# How to update Ubuntu installation USB? Ubuntu not installing additional drivers only after Update

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, updates

I made [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gRnyyCN8aNA) of my problem

Here are two screenshots from the video.

I select **Using Broadcom...**

[image: Additional Drivers dialog]

Then I click <kbd>Apply Changes</kbd> and it automatically goes back to **Do not use this device**

[image: Additional Drivers dialog]

So, on Ubuntu 17.10.1 I can't install additional drivers.

I need to Install Ubuntu 17.10.1 and update it first (about 250MB of updates) then I will be able to install the additional drivers.

So I am asking if it's possible to download an up to date Ubuntu 17.10.1 installation ISO?

My WiFi will not work after installation and I have limited 4G internet from my iPhone and I don't have enough internet to install 250MB updates + the WiFi driver.

Comment: Unfortunately, you're going to have a hard time getting folks to watch a video to figure out what you need help with. It's a little hard to tell from your question what you've tried and what the full error you're encountering is.

Comment: @Amanda We can install additional drivers on Ubuntu right? on Ubuntu 17.10.1 we cant because this feature not working normally and it load the drivers but couldn't install them, we need to update Ubuntu 17.10.1 first then we will be able to install additional drivers. so I asked if it's possible to download an up to date 17.10.1 ISO

Comment: Meky, in general it's a good idea ask directly about your real problem, not about how to implement a solution you think might work. [What is the XY problem?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) Your real problem is that Additional Drivers does not work. Changing the ISO to fix that will be hard. There is probably a better way.

Comment: @Zanna Thanks, so you mean it's better to delete my answer?

Comment: No! Your answer was fine (it was upvoted by me). I mean, instead of asking about how to update the ISO, ask about the additional drivers problem. But anyway you fixed your problem...

Answer (score 1):

This problem was solved by using an older Ubuntu 17.10 (not 17.10.1) installation DVD.